# Relation between Fourier Transform Duality and other properties.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I'm having a hard time with Fourier Transform's Duality Property.

The Duality Property states that, if $$\mathcal{F}\left\{x(t)\right\} = X(\nu),$$ then $$\mathcal{F}\left\{X(t)\right\} = 2\pi x(-\nu).$$

How does this property interacts with other properties of the Fourier Transform? For example, knowing that $$\mathcal{F}\left\{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} t} x(t) \right\} = i\nu X(\nu),$$ applying the Duality Property, one finds that $$\mathcal{F}\left\{i t x(t) \right\} = 2\pi \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}(-\nu)} X(-\nu).$$ The correct property, as stated in Wikipedia, is that $$\mathcal{F}\left\{i t x(t) \right\} = -\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\nu} X(\nu).$$

I can't find the error, nor can I see where the $2\pi$ came from. I couldn't interchange between the two results, proving that they are the same.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you defining the Fourier Transform? That can affect the identities.

Comment: "its proof is rather simple"  ??? no, forget it, it is everything BUT simple..

Comment: and [there are two Fourier transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Units_and_Duality) : the one with some normalization constants ($\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}$ and $\xi = \frac{\omega}{2 \pi}$) and the one without, this is simply why it differs of a $2 \pi$ constant, and for the rest it is because you made a mistake by applying the [Fourier inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem) (that's its name)

Comment: Sorry, I'm going along with the definition of my Signal Analysis book, I'll rewrite my question in terms of $\nu$.

Comment: I'm defining $F(\nu) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) e^{-i\nu t} \text{d}t$, so that $f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(\nu) e^{i \nu t} \text{d}\nu$. The properties seem to be correct, I guess, I proved them being consistent with my notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've applied the duality property wrongly. What you should get is

$$\mathcal{F}\{it X(t)\}=-2\pi\frac{dx(-\nu)}{d\nu}\tag{1}$$

Note that $X(t)$ is the Fourier transform of $x(\nu)$, not the other way around, as you supposed in your equation. Let

$$\tilde{X}(\nu)=\mathcal{F}\{X(t)\}\tag{2}$$

From the duality property we know that

$$\tilde{X}(\nu)=2\pi x(-\nu)\tag{3}$$

Plugging $(3)$ into $(1)$ gives

$$\mathcal{F}\{it X(t)\}=-\frac{d\tilde{X}(\nu)}{d\nu}\tag{4}$$

which is equivalent to the last equation in your question.

Comment: You know, now that you explained, I feel silly. :) I _kinda_ thought that carelessly mixing $x(t)$ and $X(\nu)$ wouldn't affect the result, but it did. Found the problem, thank you.